# my action bar is so thin and the menu is not displayed

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu, android-actionbar-compat

[this is the main activity where no menu item is showing and the action bar is so thin waht should i do to show menu item]

> [image]

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    public ListView listView;
    //public ScrollView mScrollView;
    public ScrollView mScrollView2;
    public TextView mTextView;
    private static final int CATEGORY_DETAIL = 1;
    private static final int NO_MEMORY_CARD = 2;
    private static final int TERMS = 3;

    public RadioButton radEnable;
    public RadioButton radDisable;

    private static Resources res;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        res = getResources();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
         //mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01);
        mScrollView2 = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView02);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNoRecords);

        SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences(
                Constants.LISTEN_ENABLED, 0);
        boolean silentMode = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", true);

        if (silentMode)
            showDialog(CATEGORY_DETAIL);

        context = this.getBaseContext();
        // showDialog(TERMS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        ....
    }

    /**
     * checks if an external memory card is available
     *
     * @return
     */
    public static int updateExternalStorageState() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        //return true;

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences(
                Constants.LISTEN_ENABLED, 0);
        boolean silentMode = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", true);

        MenuItem menuDisableRecord = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_Disable_record);
        MenuItem menuEnableRecord = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_Enable_record);

        // silent is disabled, disableRecord item must be disabled
        menuEnableRecord.setEnabled(silentMode);
        menuDisableRecord.setEnabled(!silentMode);

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Toast toast;
        final Activity currentActivity = this;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_about:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle(R.string.about_title)
                        .setMessage(R.string.about_content)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.about_close_button,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                }).show();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_Disable_record:
                setSharedPreferences(true);
                toast = Toast.makeText(this,
                        this.getString(R.string.menu_record_is_now_disabled),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_Enable_record:
                setSharedPreferences(false);
                // activateNotification();
                toast = Toast.makeText(this,
                        this.getString(R.string.menu_record_is_now_enabled),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_see_terms:
                Intent i = new Intent(this.getBaseContext(), TermsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.menu_privacy_policy:
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://www.privacychoice.org/policy/mobile?policy=306ef01761f300e3c30ccfc534babf6b"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                break;
            case R.id.menu_delete_all:
                AlertDialog.Builder builderDelete = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        MainActivity.this);
                builderDelete
                        .setTitle(R.string.dialog_delete_all_title)
                        .setMessage(R.string.dialog_delete_all_content)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_delete_all_yes,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int id) {
                                        FileHelper
                                                .deleteAllRecords(currentActivity);
                                        onResume();
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_delete_all_no,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                }).show();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    private void setSharedPreferences(boolean silentMode) {
....
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        .......    }

    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
        .....}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_Enable_record"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_record_enable"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/menu_Enable_record"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_Disable_record"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_record_disable"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/menu_Disable_record"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_about"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_about"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/menu_about"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_see_terms"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_example"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/menu_terms"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_privacy_policy"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_example"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/menu_privacy_policy"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_delete_all"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_all"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/menu_delete_all"/>
```

style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />
```

Comment: i am new here kindly help me

Comment: parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" 
try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Comment: i changed it but now no action bar is there.. but if i also change
MainActivity extends Activity to MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity than it works fine